# Create display barcode using codeigniter with library zend barcode

Tags: php, codeigniter, zend-framework

I tried to make the barcode degnan using zend library barcode , barcode appear when running perfectly but his display case full , how to display results in a barcode into an iframe or img ???

This my Controller

```
class Contohbarcode extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

function index() {
    $this->load->view('insertcode');
}

function bikin_barcode() {
    $this->load->library('zend');
    $this->zend->load('Zend/Barcode');

    $barcode = $this->input->post('barcode');
    Zend_Barcode::render('code128', 'image', array('text'=>$barcode), array());
}

}
```

View insertcode

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>contohbarcode/bikin_barcode" class="form-horizontal">
    <div align="center">
    <input name="barcode" id="location" type="text"  placeholder="insert your code">
    </p>
    <input type="submit" class="btn" name="submit" value="Find">
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you need to save it to variable and then save it to file using e.g. `imagepng`, and then you can display that barcode as simple image

```
$imageResource = Zend_Barcode::factory('code128', 'image', array('text'=>$barcode), array())->draw();
imagepng($imageResource, 'public_html/img/barcode.png');
```

[Zend tutorial about saving barcode to imageResource](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.barcode.creation.html#zend.barcode.creation.drawing)

[PHP.net about imagepng](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php)

Comment: nice... this work , img barcode stored on a folder and I can show . thanks very much @Gvidas