# Zend barcode PNG output giving me 500 internal error in Codeigniter

Tags: php, zend-framework, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to generate Barcode in Codeigniter 3.

Here is my controller code

```
public function barcode($code)
{
    $this->load->library('Zend');
    $this->zend->load('Zend/Barcode');
    $data['active'] =1;
    // Generate barcode
    $imageResource = Zend_Barcode::render('Code128', 'image', array('text'=>$code), array());
    
    $image = $imageResource->draw();

    header('Cache-Control: public');
    header('Content-type: image/png');
    imagepng($image);
    imagedestroy($image);
}
```

I'm trying to access it like

```
http://localhost/erp/admin/Box_label/barcode/598654728634789
```

it is generating the Barcode and showing it in browser but also showing 500 internal Server error. I couldn't save it.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I've added edit, I'm calling it like this ```http://localhost/erp/admin/Box_label/barcode/myparameter``` and also tried with using inside ```<img >`` but same result

Comment: This should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35646567/create-display-barcode-using-codeigniter-with-library-zend-barcode